# Returning a reference of an object inside a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Map
{
    std::vector<Continent> continents;

public:

    Map();
    ~Map();
    Continent* getContinent(std::string name);
};

Continent* Map::getContinent(std::string name)
{
    Continent * c = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < continents.size(); i++)
    {
        if (continents[i].getName() == name)
        {
            c = &continents[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

You can see here that there are `continent` objects that live inside the `vector` called `continents`. Would this be a correct way of getting the object's reference, or is there a better approach to this? Is there an underlying issue with vector which would cause this to misbehave?

Comment: when the vector grows dynamically, it's contents get de-allocated and re-allocated. Under such scenario, it's a bad idea to get reference to a particular object within vector.

Comment: The quick and dirty fix:  use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`.  A `std::list` doesn't invalidate pointers or references if resized.  Only if you remove the item from the list will the pointer / reference be invalid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie quick and dirty meaning hackish? Would using `std::list` be the correct alternative? Would it make a difference if these objects live in the heap instead; `new` ?

Comment: @Dimitri Not really hackish, but does use more memory (if the sequence is long) and loses being contiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK to return a pointer or a reference to an object inside `std::vector` under one condition: the content of the vector must not change after you take the pointer or a reference.

This is easy to do when you initialize a vector at start-up or in the constructor, and never change it again. In situations when the vector is more dynamic than that returning by value, rather than by pointer, is a more robust approach.

Comment: In other words, if the vector is dynamic, I can never reference any of its object due to invalidation of pointers. Is there a workaround to this? What if the objects were created in the heap instead, such as :  std::vector<Continent*> continents. Does it pose the same issue?

Comment: @Dimitri A vector of pointers to heap objects is better, because adding or removing other pointers from a vector does not invalidate existing pointers. The only issue with this is that at some point you would need to delete these heap objects, so you would need to do something about potential dangling pointers. This issue would remain with or without vectors, though.

Comment: Perfect, the issue with dangling pointers will be dealt with in Map's destructor. But if they don't invalidate upon a change within the vector, then this is perfect. My vector grows dynamically during a file-read, which happens once and only once. After the objects are created, based on what was read in the file, they're stored in the vector and never change again. Although my approach would work in such a case, I'm not sure if future requirements would need to modify the vector. But if no invalidation happens, this is good.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you against doing something like the above. std::vector does some fancy way of handling memory which include resizing and moving the array when it is out of capacity which will result in a dangling reference. On the other hand if the map contains a const vector, which means it is guaranteed not to be altered, what you are doing would work.

Thanks
Sudharshan

Answer (score 1):

The design is flawed, as other have pointed out.

However, if you don't mind using more memory, lose the fact that the sequence no longer will sit in contiguous memory, and that the iterators are no longer random access, then a drop-in replacement would be to use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`.

The `std::list` does not invalidate pointers or references to the internal data when resized.  The only time when a pointer / reference is invalidated is if you are removing the item being pointed to / referred to.